# How can I propagate request headers to response headers in SpringBoot 2

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I have interfaces generated by Swagger Codegen. It looks like this:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/ipc/conf", produces = {"application/json", "application/problem+json"}, consumes = {
            "application/json"})
default ResponseEntity<CustomResponseEntity> ipcConfPost(
            @ApiParam(value = "ID", required = true) @RequestHeader(value = "X-Request-ID", required = true) String xRequestID,
            @ApiParam(value = "Value for identifying a single transaction across multiple services up to the backend.", required = true) @RequestHeader(value = "X-Correlation-ID", required = true) String xCorrelationID,
            @ApiParam(value = "The payload to transmit", required = true) @Valid @RequestBody IPcData ipcConfData,
            @ApiParam(value = "The business context is a general classification for a larger number of requests.") @RequestHeader(value = "X-Business-Context", required = false) String xBusinessContext) {
        getRequest().ifPresent(request -> {
            for (MediaType mediaType : MediaType.parseMediaTypes(request.getHeader("Accept"))) {
                if (mediaType.isCompatibleWith(MediaType.valueOf("application/json"))) {
                    String exampleString = "{ \"id\" : \"id\", \"error\" : \"error\" }";
                    ApiUtil.setExampleResponse(request, "application/json", exampleString);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
    }
```

In the implementation I want to have a full list of request headers (I need some of them in the response) or to be able to get a value of a header that is not listed in the API. The thing is I **cannot** change the signature of the endpoint since it will cause a major headache in further releases.
So is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Just add the `HttpServletRequest` as a parameter to access the headers. That won't change the external API and you have access to everything you need. If you are lucky you can instruct swagger to do so, if not, as a hack you could use `RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()` which you can cast to a `WebRequest` to get the headers.

Comment: I can't: the API is automatically generated on every build so I cannot effectively modify the interface.

Comment: You'll always have this if you rely on generated code (it similar but not the same as teams using JPA to create their DB schema). The best solution is to separate them , you'll have to manually update both the swagger file and API, but it will give you flexibility. And be careful that *if* you find a solution, that it doesn't require 2 PHDs to understand it.

Comment: DOn't generate then ;). If the framework prevents you from doing things in the way they should, it is limiting you and ditch it. But as stated you can use the hack with the `RequestContextHolder` to get the current request. Still imho it is a hack and you should be able to configure the generator to add the `HttpServletRequest` (or `WebRequest`) as a parameter.

Comment: Well, I'll do this as my last resort.
I thought there could be some clever way to get the headers so I decided to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the request object in your code already so you can get the headers from it. i.e. `request.getHeaderNames()` then loop through them.

After that, you can add them to the response with

```
HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
responseHeaders.set("key", "value");
ResponseEntity.ok().headers(responseHeaders).body("some body");
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this. Thank you! :)
In case of someone will face the same situation: I Autowired the request in a constructor of my controller and iterated over headers in the implementation of the method of the interface.